# Game of Score Four

Tags: combinatorics

How many possible sequences of length 64 and made from the characters 0123456789ABCDEF are there, where each character appears exactly 4 times.

(This is no homework! I am trying to calculate an upper bound for the number of possible games in the game of "score four")

thank you!
kind regards
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number you are looking for is called a multinomial coefficient.  It is equal to
$$
{64 \choose 4, 4, \dots, 4} = \frac{64!}{(4!)^{16}},
$$
which is a very large number indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer.
$$
N=\binom{64}{4}\binom{60}{4}\cdots\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}=\frac{64!}{(4!)^{16}}\approx 1.047\times 10^{67}
$$

So, we place the 1s in $\binom{64}{4}$ ways, next the 2s in $\binom{60}{4}$ ways etc.

Answer (score 1):

Start by placing the $0$ four times. There are $\binom{64}{4}$ possibilities.

Then place the $1$ four times. There are $\binom{60}{4}$ possibilities.

Et cetera.

This leads to $$\binom{64}{4}\binom{60}{4}\cdots\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}=\frac{64!}{\left(4!\right)^{16}}$$
possibilities.

---

**alternative**

There are $64!$ possibilities to put the characters in a sequence of length $64$ if there would be distinction between $4$ characters that are 'of the same sort'. To repair this double counting we must divide by $4!$ and this for any of the $16$ sorts of character. This leads directly to $$\frac{64!}{\left(4!\right)^{16}}$$